# UnityのC#でeval()のようなことがしたい

Tags: c#, unity3d

ソケット通信で受け取った文字列をeval()で実行しようと思って調べたんですが、UnityのC#ではセキュリティリスクがあるとかでeval()が無いと出てきました。

代わりにeval()と似たようなことをする方法はないでしょうか？

Comment: 検索しただけで、エディタの拡張のようですが、参考になるかも。[MrJoy/UnityREPL](https://github.com/MrJoy/UnityREPL), [rje/unishell](https://github.com/rje/unishell), [C# Interactive 便利に使おう -その１ DLLの参照-](http://esprog.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/06/22/181915), [C# Interactive 便利に使おう -その２ UnityAssemblyの参照-](http://esprog.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/10/13/001540)

Comment: 同様に少し古いようですが、あるプロジェクトと日本語の記事。[Unity で実行時に補完付きで REPL を行うプラグインの複数行対応をした](http://tips.hecomi.com/entry/2016/08/18/020411), [Unity で実行時にコードやコマンドを補完つきで実行できる uREPL を作ってみた](http://tips.hecomi.com/entry/2015/12/05/003000)

Comment: 簡単な数式だけでよいのか、Unityの機能も呼び出すのか、などによって最適解が変わるかもしれないので、実行する具体的なコードの例を記載してはどうでしょうか